# 2.8 setting up different viewport shading options for different viewport windows?

Tags: 3d-view

hopefully this makes sense.

But can you set up different viewport shading options for different viewport windows?

ie if I'm using the Quad window viewports (see image) can I have X-Ray shading in all viewports except for the ortho viewport, because in the ortho viewport I just want a wireframe shading (or even hiding the blueprint objects).

[image]

Comment: If you split the areas manually, then yes it's possibly. Unfortunately that doesn't seem to work for the quad view, because all settings are applied to all areas.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks guys, so looks like what I'm after is...

1) Setup 4 viewports (don't use Quad View),

2) Make all of them Ortho viewports except the top right viewport (ie make it Perspective)

3) Then in the perspective viewport  select the blueprint Empty object and in Object Data turn off Display Perspective

Giving me wireframes against the blueprints, but a solid view of the tank in a perspective view without the distraction of the blueprints, ie...

[image]

Thanks again.